# Numerical accuracy of multivariate normal distribution

Tags: matlab, covariance

In MATLAB, I've written two snippets of code that compute the PDF of a multivariate normal distribution. However there's a difference in the values these two methods produce and I can't figure out why. I've narrowed the problem down to something having to do with computing the inverse of the covariance matrix.

Inaccurate code

```
function p = mvnpdf_inacc(X, mu, sigma)
    xc = bsxfun(@minus, X, mu);
    [n, k] = size(xc);
    twopic = (2 * pi) ^ (-k / 2);
    sqrtdetsig = sqrt(det(sigma)) ^ -1;
    c = twopic * sqrtdetsig;
    p = zeros(n, 1);
    for i = 1:n
        xci = xc(i, :);
        p(i) = c * exp(-0.5 * (xci / sigma * xci'));
    end
end
```

Accurate code

```
function p = mvnpdf_acc(X, mu, sigma)
    [R, err] = cholcov(sigma, 0);

    if err
        error('%s', 'sigma is not both symmetric and positive definite');
    end

    X0 = bsxfun(@minus, X, mu) / R;
    d = min(size(X));
    slogdet = sum(log(diag(R)));
    p = exp(-0.5 * sum(X0 .^ 2, 2) - slogdet - 0.5 * d * log(2 * pi));
end
```

Testing code

```
function iseq_func = test_mvnpdf(n)
    x = linspace(-2, 2, n);
    y = x;
    [X, Y] = meshgrid(x, y);
    XY = [X(:), Y(:)];
    mu = [0, 0];
    sigma = [1.0, 0.5; 0.5, 0.4];
    p_inacc = mvnpdf_inacc(XY, mu, sigma);
    p_acc = mvnpdf_acc(XY, mu, sigma);
    p_diff = abs(p_inacc - p_acc);
    iseq_func = nnz(p_diff) == 0;
end
```

I get a value of false from running `iseq_func(25)`. What the heck is going on here? Thanks!

Comment: Why not use the built-in mvnpdf?

Comment: @varty because it is 'built-in' to the \$tati\$tic\$ toolbox, which is _another thousand dollars_ or so.

Comment: This is more likely to be a roundoff issue than a matrix inversion problem. The bottom version works in log likelihood space and takes the exponent in the last step. This is going to allow vast differences in magnitude to be summed without the roundoff issues.

Comment: Where is the multiplication by $-1/2$ in the exponent in the first calculation? Am I just not seeing it?

Comment: I compared the accuracy to `mvnpdf` because I have the statistics toolbox and in fact the more accurate version is just a less general version of that function. I can't use `mvnpdf` for this particular assignment. I've already completed the assignment, I was just wondering why this happens. @shabbyshef Is there a short version of why the roundoff error here is the problem? I'd like to be able to explain this to someone in my class. If not can you point me in the direction of some materials?

Comment: I would pay attention to @cardinal's comment first.  Roundoff error might account for differences beyond the 12th significant figure or so, and the product-vs-logarithmic approach could account for overflow problems when they occur, but otherwise neither can explain noticeable differences in the results.

Comment: With @cardinal's correction (edited into the question it appears), I do not get any difference between the two versions. However, I had to change the `cholcov` to `chol`, because the former is in the statistics toolbox. (See http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/stats/cholcov.html ). This may be the rub, however: I was testing the two implementations with a positive definite `sigma`. If that condition does not hold, then `cholcov` does something odd, which might explain inconsistencies, if they still exist.

Comment: @shabbychef `cholcov` calls `chol`. The difference is that various flags allow the user to check for positive definiteness using eigenvalue decomposition via the `eig` function. How did you test for differences?

Comment: @cpcloud: Please provide the output of `sum(p_diff)` and `mean(p_diff)`. It seems likely that `nnz` is simply not returning zero due to minor differences in the floating-point calculations. I expect even `sum(p_diff)` to be very small.

Comment: @cardinal Yes, the whole point of my question is that there is any difference whatsoever. I'm wondering why that is (other than just simply minor differences in floating-point calculations). `max(p_diff)` is something like `5e-14`. Why should there be any difference *at all*?

Comment: Machine epsilon for double-precision floating point is `2.2e-16`. Each of your calculations involves a few hundred floating point operations, at the least. Is this what you meant by *inaccurate* the whole time? (I'm assuming not, since before the correction due to my original comment you would have seen differences many, many orders of magnitude larger.)

Comment: I've always been running the code with the -0.5 in there. It was only the first time I pasted it onto stats.stackexchange.com that I forgot the constant. OK, so the machine epsilon is `2.2e-16`, but so what? One of the functions is returning an answer that is different by a factor of 100 at its largest value. My question still remains...what causes this difference and why should one method be more accurate than the other? Maybe I don't understand floating point operations and round-off error at a deep enough level.

Comment: I found http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.102.244&rep=rep1&type=pdf (What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic) at http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/1168/what-papers-should-everyone-read. I haven't read it yet, but I'm hoping I'll be able to answer my own question after reading it.

Comment: wait, you're joking. the innacuracies you are asking about are on the order of $10^{-14}$?

Comment: @shabbychef lol. No I'm not joking. I'm going to close the question because it seems this problem is insignificant. It was more a question of interest than one of an actual problem per se.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing you tested the code using a `sigma` which is not positive semidefinite. The 'accurate' implementation (which I am guessing is from the statistics toolbox) is computing $y^{\top}y$ where $y = C^{-\top} \left(x - \mu\right)$ where $C$ is the output of `cholcov` on $\Sigma$ (`sigma`). Note that $y^{\top}y$ *must* be non-negative by design. If you feed in a $\Sigma$ which is not PD, `cholcov` silently returns some version of $C$ and the rest of the code proceeds (I would have made this an error, I think).

The code you wrote, however, is computing $\left(x - \mu\right)^{\top}\Sigma^{-1}\left(x - \mu\right)$. If $\Sigma$ is not PD, this quantity can be negative.

When $\Sigma$ is positive definite, `cholcov` returns a proper Cholesky factorization, and the results are the same (up to round off).

Comment: I used the matrix `sigma = [1.0, 0.5; 0.5, 0.4];`.

Comment: My matrix is plenty symmetric. Run `sigma == sigma'` in MATLAB.

Comment: @cpcloud : this is not a problem of symmetry, it is whether the matrix is positive definite. Try, for example `sigma = [1.0, -1.4;-1.4, 0.2]`. `chol` bonks, but `cholcov` returns some matrix (I am guessing. I do not have the statistics toolbox).